# Error in Implementing WCF service inside web application

Tags: wcf

I am getting following error in my web application implementing `WCF Service` method 'Add Numbers'. I am using JSON response format:

> Server Error in '/' Application. Operation 'AddNumbers' of contract
> 'ICalculator' specifies multiple request body parameters to be
> serialized without any wrapper elements. At most one body parameter
> can be serialized without wrapper elements.
>
> Either remove the extra
> body parameters or set the BodyStyle property on the
> WebGetAttribute/WebInvokeAttribute to Wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue after searching in the google.

Actually the problem is in web.config file of web application.

I changed a bit of code in it.I added `<webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped"/>`
only and hence Solved

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="AllocationBehavior">
      <webHttp defaultBodyStyle="Wrapped" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<client>
  <endpoint name="Default"
            address="http://localhost:3876/Calculator.svc"
            binding="webHttpBinding"
            behaviorConfiguration="AllocationBehavior"
            contract="ServiceReference1.ICalculator" />
</client>
```